# Spring CrudRepository implement interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am currently learning Spring CrudRepository. I create a base repository for other classes to inherit later, below is my code:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID>
{
}
```

Do I need to create a class that implements the `BaseRepository` interface? If yes, how to implement them? any example? Or I just left it blank and Spring will do the jobs? 
I try it with simple code as below:
**LoginBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean
{
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public LoginBean()
    {
    }

    public void saveAcc()
    {
        System.out.println("Save Acc");
        accountRepository.save(new Account("username", "password", 1));
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

but I get `NullPointerException`

```
Warning:   java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:293)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.peter.uass.bean.LoginBean.saveAcc(LoginBean.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    ... 41 more

Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.peter.uass.bean.LoginBean.saveAcc(LoginBean.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE**
OK I have found the problem, the `NullPointerException` is because my autowired accountRepository is null, any idea?

Comment: because you explicitly marked your `BaseRepository` to be `@NoRepositoryBean`, of course Spring Data is not going to create a bean for it.  What are you trying to do actually?  You should create an interface for your Account (i.e. `interface AccountRepository extends BaseRepository<Account, WHATEVER>` and inject that.

Comment: Yes because you explicitly marked your BaseRepository to be @NoRepositoryBean, you should implement it, I recommend creating repository class that implement it with extra methods you want to implement .

Comment: I created AccountRepository interface and I still get `NullPointerException`, my class : `@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends BaseRepository<Account, Integer>{}`

Comment: Why are you creating an intermediate interface instead of extending `CrudRepository` directly?

Comment: What are you trying to achive with your `BaseRepository`? Otherwise it is kind of hard to help you with your problem

Comment: Can u pls post how did u finally solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

the base repository interface must extend the same interface that is extended by your repository interfaces. In other words, if your repository interfaces extend the CrudRepository interface, the BaseRepository interface must extend it as well.

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl <T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>  implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {



  private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Optional<T> deleteById(ID id) {
        T deleted = entityManager.find(this.getDomainClass(), id);
        Optional<T> returned = Optional.empty();

        if (deleted != null) {
            entityManager.remove(deleted);
            returned = Optional.of(deleted);
        }
        return returned;
    }
}
```

for more you can refer this below link :

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/

Comment: What is your `SimpleJpaRepository` class?

Answer (score 0):

BTW there is no need of `BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>` in your case, as you haven't defined any new method in this repository. And so you can create an interface for each of your Entity directly extending `CrudRepository`. 
Note:

```
@Autowired
private BaseRepository baseRepository;
```

Doesn't work because you have already mark `BaseRepository` as `@NoRepositoryBean`.

So just create an interface for your entity like for entity `AccountDetail`, you can do something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<AccountDetail, String>
{
  //Can add any custom method you want, but not necessary.
}
```

And finally use it like:

```
@Autowired
private AccountDetailRepository accountRepository;
public void saveAcc()
{
    System.out.println("Save Acc");
    accountRepository.save(new AccountDetail("username", "password", 1));
}
```

Comment: I still get error `javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @Newbie Have you created bean for class in which you are autowiring AccountDetailRepository  object?

Comment: Update full error stack already. and what bean is that? I am calling `saveAcc()` function in my `loginBean`, any guide on how to do it correctly? sorry I am new in JSF, Hibernate and Spring

Answer (score 0):

To work with Spring Data JPA repositories you don't need to implement them. You can just extend them:

```
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
}
```

where `MyEntity` is your entity which you want to store/read from the database, and `Integer` is a type of `MyEntity` primary key marked by `@Id` annotation:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    // fields, getters, setters and other stuff
}
```

When you create your repo interface then you can use all basic methods that extended repositories are providing: `save`, `delete`, `findAll` and other (see javadocs: [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html), [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html), [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)...).

To use repo methods all you need is to inject your repo to the repo variable, for example:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class MyEntityService {

    @Autoware
    private MyEntityRepo repo;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<MyEntity> findAll() {

        return repo.findAll();
    }  

    public void save(MyEntity entity) {

        repo.save(entity);
    }

    public void delete(MyEntity entity) {

        repo.delete(entity);
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Spring Data JPA reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)
- [Getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: I have a doubt here,spring instantiates class right?? so how are we using autowired for reference of interface??.